# where and how to put a picture closing button in my html page

Tags: html

I am stuck. I have a site where people can check my lists, and can click on a code and see a larger picture in a window that opens after. I'd like this larger picture to have a closing option (an "X") somewhere up right. And can not find the place in my HTML page to do it.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks! Tomas http://www.patentesantiguas.com.ar/galeria/repetidas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is really interesting. Is it vintage license plates? What I can recommend is to link to another html page instead of a jpeg image and open in new tab (target="_blank"). Also append the image name to url so that you can get image file name into javascript variable.

```
<a target="_blank" href="yourimageviewer.html?currentimage=yourlicenseplateimagenamehere.jpg">
```

After the html link to the new page use a question mark to pass in the variable of the image you want to display.

On the target page ("yourimageviewer.html") you can use javascript to get the image name variable and display on the page with the x to close it. Since the filename is a variable you only have to put in the links for all of the different files instead of creating a viewer for each page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="closeWindow()">X</button>
        <img id="currImage" src="defaultImage.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%">


       <script>
        <!--BELOW GETS VARIABLE FROM URL-->


 function getPictureName() {
            var pictures = {};
            var urlVariables = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                pictures[key] = value;
            });
            return pictures;
        }

        var image = getPictureName()["currentimage"];
        var path = "yourimagepath/"
        document.getElementById('currImage').src = path + image;



        function closeWindow() {
          window.close();
        }


        </script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you NetizenCaine! And sorry for not responding any earier, but I was too busy with my work. This site is my hobby. Yes, they are all original very old license plates. 4 years collecting them. I will try to solve it soon, and thank you for your interest. Regards! Tom

Comment: Hi again Netizen: I am done with your fantastic recommendation, the link to another page containing a variable picture works fine, even the "X" button does (what I wanted). Except, that the image it is supposed to call, does not show up. I tried different ways, but I can't find the error. Maybe you can check and advise. Thank you once again, Tom

Comment: http://patentesantiguas.com.ar/galeria/spare-prices-prueba.html

Comment: Make sure to remove "yourimagepath/" too from path variable. Replace with var path ="images/" or whichever path directs to where that image is

Comment: Yes! I could do it now! I am very greatful!!! Thank you for taking your time to help me. Until next time! Tom

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is more appropriate as a comment, but I couldnt comment. On your button, you navigate to the image URL (eg. http://www.patentesantiguas.com.ar/galeria/250/E3G.JPG), which from what I know, could not have a button on top of it.

You will need to make a page or overlay with the html image element,

So your current page button will navigate you to the new html or open the overlay instead of opening the image.

Then your page will have

```
[![][1]][1]
```

which display the image, then have a button to go back to history (-1) page

```
 <button onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" >Close</button>
```

Hopefully this is helpful

Comment: Thank you Bulaxy! And sorry for not responding any earier, but I was too busy with my work. This site is my hobby. I think I got your point, and I will try. Regards! Tom

Comment: @PATENTESANTIGUAS All good~ Soon after I posted this post, I saw @NetizenCaine answer which I believe is straightly better than mine, I notice you have follow through with that answer which is good!   

Regarding to the error you having, I had a look at your page, you need to change `var path = "yourimagepath/"` in the javascript. He left it as `yourimagepath` as in your file path. which I believe would at least involve `var path = "maybe something/250/"`

Comment: Thank you @Bulaxy for your kind help. Yes!! I am sure there is the problem. I am not an expert so, all changes take me some time to understand. I will try it tonight, after work, and let you know. Thank you guys for your help!!!!! I really appreciate your time, Tom

Comment: Yes! I could do it now! I am very greatful!!! Thank you for taking your time to help me. Until next time! Tom

Comment: @PATENTESANTIGUAS Happy to help. You might want to set NetizenCaine as the answer to helps others search the answer. Also, both him and I dont have enough reputation to comments on other post, so sounds like bragging, but upvoting would help us earn reputation to comment on other post. (eg. my previous comment ideally would have been commented on his post) (Only upvote stuff that you found useful tho, dont just upvote everything)

Answer (score 0):

check  this  if you want to use vanilla JavaScript

https://www.cssscript.com/mini-lightbox-popup-with-vanilla-javascript/

or if you want to use jquery  use this easy to implement

https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

Comment: Thank you Rkv88 - Kanyan! And sorry for not responding any earier, but I was too busy with my work. This site is my hobby. I will check your recommendation. Regards! Tom